# Memory allocation

Tags: c, memory-management, struct, malloc, realloc

```
typedef struct {
    float *numbers;
    float val1;
    float val2;
} Values; 
Values val[16];
```

How can one allocate memory for numbers in the struct?

Comment: One can use malloc(). What have you tried doing so far?

Comment: We know one can use malloc(). I'm asking for a proper use.

Comment: what does your C textbook have to say on the subject? Your  question is akin to "how can I do addition".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you could do this without using dynamic memory allocation like this:

```
typedef struct {
    float *numbers;
    float val1;
    float val2;
} Values; 

#define MAX_SIZE 16

int main() {
    Values val[MAX_SIZE];
    float myfloats[MAX_SIZE];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<MAX_SIZE;i++) {
        val[i].numbers=&myfloats[i];
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

But I can't think of any reason why you'd want a structure with a pointer to just one float.

Based on the name `'numbers'`, I'd say you want `'numbers'` to point to an array of `floats`, if so, you could do this:

```
#include <malloc.h>

typedef struct {
    float *numbers;
    float val1;
    float val2;
} Values; 

#define MAX_SIZE 16

int main() {
    Values val[MAX_SIZE];
    size_t numberOfFloats = 10;
    int i;

    // for each of the members of the val array
    for(i=0;i<MAX_SIZE;i++) {
        // allocate using calloc (this will set all of the floats to 0.0)
        val[i].numbers=calloc(numberOfFloats,sizeof(float));

        // check the allocation worked...
        if(!val[i].numbers) {
            // insert proper error handling here.
            printf("oops\n");
            return -1;
        }

    }

    // you access the variables like this
    for(i=0;i<MAX_SIZE;i++) {
        int number;
        for(number=0; number < numberOfFloats; number++) {
            printf("Value %d, Number %d = %f\n",i,number,val[i].numbers[number]);
        }
    }

    // don't forget to play nice and clean up afterwards
    for(i=0;i<MAX_SIZE;i++) {
        free(val[i].numbers);
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to allocate the space for one float in the first element of your struct, you would do it like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

/* ... */

val[0].numbers = malloc(1 * sizeof(float)); /* "1 * " for clarity... */
```

If that's what you meant.